# How can i convert multiple text files into same filename with .html files format using perl?

Tags: perl

```
Code which i have tried for single file:

#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $HTML, '>', 'h.html' or die $!;

print $HTML <<'_END_HEADER_';
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
_END_HEADER_

open my $IN, '<', 'h.txt' or die $!;
while (my $line = <$IN>) {
    # You probably want to do more work here.
    print $HTML $line;
}

print $HTML '</body></html>';
close $HTML or die $!;
```

Query:

The above code converts .txt to .html file format.In this code i have tried for single file.I got struck with how can i do for multiple files from the folder using perl?

Input files:

```
h.txt
e.txt
l.txt
```

Expected output;(With html formt)

```
h.html
e.html
l.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html). It return the list of filename for mentioned directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open my $HTML, '>', 'h.html' or die $!;

print $HTML <<'_END_HEADER_';
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
_END_HEADER_

while (my $file= glob("~/Desktop/*.txt"))
{
    open my $IN, '<', $file or die $!;

    while (my $line = <$IN>) 
    {
        print $HTML $line;
    }
}


print $HTML '</body></html>';
close $HTML or die $!;
```

Writing into new file

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $HTML;
#open my $HTML, '>', 'h.html' or die $!;


while (my $file= glob("~/Desktop/*.txt"))
{
    open my $IN, '<', $file or die $!;
    my $new_file_name = $file;
    $new_file_name=~s/.+\///;
    open $HTML, '>', "$new_file_name.html" or die $!;
    print $HTML "
    <html>
    <head><title></title></head>
    <body>";
    while (my $line = <$IN>) 
    {
        print $HTML $line;
    }
    print $HTML '</body></html>';
    close $HTML;
}
```

Comment: Great keyword for reading multiple files .How can we write mutliple files with the reading file names.Here we have done every readable file contents into the single file.I had mentioned the expected output.Could you please make a note of it.@mkHun

Comment: Global symbol "$HTML" requires explicit package name at text1.pl line 8.
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at text1.pl line 16.@mkHun

Comment: Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference@mkHun

Comment: Great it helps me@mkHun